# Difference between normal pointer and const pointer in c

Tags: c, pointers

I don't know the difference between a normal pointer and a `const` pointer. The below code works fine, but when I change `int *ptr=&num;` to `int *const ptr = &var1;` then it does not.
What is the difference between a normal pointer and a `const` pointer?

```
 int main(void)
    {
        int num = 20;
     int  *ptr = &num ; // if i change to   `int *const ptr = &var1;` then it shows some error

     *ptr = 20 ;              // Valid 
     ptr ++ ;                 // valid

        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int* const ptr = &num ;
```

Will create a constant pointer to an int. The data it points to can be changed, but the pointer it self cannot.

You cannot change the pointer:

```
ptr++ ;
```

But you can change the data:

```
*ptr = 1234 ;
```

Comment: @ArunPrasanth If you know that the pointer should always point to the same location, you can make it const.

Answer (score 3):

We **can** do following operations on *constant pointers*

- Assigning value at address
- Printing value or address
- Assigning Address at the time of declaration.

We **Can't** to following operation on *constant pointers*

- Adding Integers to Constant pointers.
- Subtracting integers to constant pointers.
- Any Operation that can change address of pointer.

So, Here in your question..

If you declare

```
int* const ptr = &num ; // this is ok
```

next line

```
*ptr = 20 ;  // Assigning value at address this is ok
```

Now,

```
ptr ++ ;  // you can not change the value // Error!
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
int* const ptr = &num ;
```

will create a **constant pointer** to an integer. You can use it to modify the integer's value but you can't change where the pointer points, thus `ptr++ ;` is invalid.

The `const` keyword is usually applied to its left symbol, e.g.

```
int * const ptr; // A constant pointer (*)
int const * ptr; // A pointer to a constant integer
int const * const ptr; // A constant pointer to a constant integer
const int *ptr; // Shorthand for pointer to a constant integer (equivalent to int const * ptr;)
```

`const` pointers are useful when you want to pass a fixed memory location around and you want to make sure that nobody will modify the pointer's pointed address.

Answer (score 1):

in c, `const` is a `type qualifier`. use of `const` in some variable definition means, the variable will not get modified (will be treated as `read-only`)during the entire lifetime of the program.

Usually, when defining a variable / data type with `const`, the pratice is to initialize it with required value, as normally, the value it holds cannot be modified at a later part.

For example:

`const int a = 10;`

means, the integer `a` will hold the value `10` and it cannot be changed. at a later part,

```
a = 20;
```

will produce error.

So, in your case

```
int *const ptr = &var;
```

here, `ptr` will always hold the address of `var` and it cannot be changed, i.e., we cannot write

```
ptr = &num2; // where num2 is another int, declared like int num2;
```

it will show compile-time error like :

> error:assignment of read-only variable "*ptr".

You can find a nice and handy description [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/const-qualifier-in-c/).

Answer (score 1):

```
int* const pointer = &x ;
```

it create a constant pointer to an int. The data it points to can be changed, but the pointer it self cannot be changed

You cannot change the pointer:

```
pointer++ ;
```

here you can change the data:

```
*pointer=1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of **normal pointer**, both the **value of pointer** & **value @ pointer** can be change.But as the pointer change the **value @ pointer** automatically change to some garbage value.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   int val = 5;
   int *ptr = (int*)&val;

   printf("val@ptr : %d \nptr     : %x\n", *(ptr), (int*)ptr);

   val++;
   printf("\nIncrement val++\n");
   printf("val@ptr : %d \nptr     : %x\n", *(ptr), (int*)ptr);

   ptr++;
   printf("\nIncrement ptr++\n");
   printf("val@ptr : %d \nptr     : %x\n", *(ptr), (int*)ptr);

   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
val@ptr : 5 
ptr     : 93ddc274

Increment val++
val@ptr : 6 
ptr     : 93ddc274

Increment ptr++
val@ptr : -1814183304 
ptr     : 93ddc278
```

But in case of **const pointer**, only the **value @ pointer** can be change not the pointer. See the below example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   int val = 10;
   //always start reading from right to left
   int *const ptr = (int*)&val;//ptr is const pointer to int, i.e. ptr can not be change at all.

   printf("The value1 @ptr : %d\t and ptr val : %x\n", *(ptr), (int*)ptr);
   val++;
   //ptr++;
   printf("The value1 @ptr : %d\t and ptr val : %x\n", *(ptr), (int*)ptr);

   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
The value1 @ptr : 10     and ptr val : ee2ccf24
The value1 @ptr : 11     and ptr val : ee2ccf24
```

If we un-comment the line number 11, then output would be like this:

```
main.c:11:7: error: increment of read-only variable ‘ptr’
    ptr++;
```

Please go through the link to get better understanding : http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html